# Entity Framework 4 (Assocations configured with filters)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ado.net

I have a user entity that contains a collection of survey entities. i would like the assocation to include a filter on the relationship, such as 'IsCompleted', so whenever i eager load (or lazy load for that matter) the collection, this filtering happens.

Is this something we have control over?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a DB back-end that supports views, you might consider using the view as the source for the collection of survey entities. Leverage the power of the DB to do that filtering for you.

Answer (score 0):

Loading of associations for an entity always just gets them all, whether because you used Include during the initial query, called Load after the fact, or lazy-loading caused it. The concept of the navigation property kind of assumes this behavior.

[E.J. Brennan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677262/entity-framework-4-assocations-configured-with-filters/7677393#7677393) would work well. If you're not concerned about loading all surveys behind the scenes (because of performance/memory reasons or something) then you might also consider creating a separate property via a partial class definition on your entity that returns the filtered list.

```
public partial class User
{
    public ICollection<Survey> CompletedSurveys
    {
        get { return Surveys.Where(s => s.IsCompleted); }
    }
}
```

Comment: thats seems like an important missing feature that other ORM's support and it is pretty critical in enterprise apps. thanks.

Comment: How is it a missing feature? As shown, it is fairly trivial to add filtered collections to an entity via partial classes. Are you expecting it to be an option in the EDMX designer? The issue with that is the entity model concerns only the schema and relationships. It's an artifact of the relationship existing and being known to EF that the entity object classes it generates come with a convenient navigational property. Custom association filters are beyond the scope of the entity model definition, and easily solved with LINQ/code anyway.

Comment: the example you provided filters the collection in-memory and when dealing with lots of records with associated collections that belong to the aggregate, you are painting yourself into a corner.